# I am unable to see X-Axis and Y-axis options in my version of power Bi. My office does allow to upgrade it. Need a solution to fix this

Tags: powerbi

I am unable to see X-Axis and Y-axis options in my version of power Bi. My office does allow to upgrade it. Need a solution to fix this. Have added the screen shot here.
[image]

Comment: I see X-Axis on the screenshot and for Y-Axis you take Values.

Answer (score 0):

As you are selecting a bar-graph, the field `axis` in Visualizations pane corresponds to the `x-axis` and the field `values` corresponds to `y-axis`.